# How do I sign with web3.py?

Tags: web3.py, python

Can I have some clarification on what is the first argument of `web3.eth.sign`.

- it says here that the first argument is a `account`-- **What is an account? Is it my ethereum address or a private key**.
- it says to make sure "the account must be unlocked" -- **Im not dealing with geth. How do I unlock my account?**

I am just writing test on my smart contract deployment on Ganache and now I need to sign something with a private key hopefully with one of the local account I control on Ganache.

I have tried inserting my ethereum address. After using `ecrecover` to verify the signer of the signature, I found that the account signing is done by an address `0x3f17f1962B36e491b30A40b2405849e597Ba5FB5` -- apparently this is the address generated from the private key `000..0`. Which makes sense because I think I should be passing something like a private key (not the address), hence this api confuses me.

```
web3.eth.sign(
      <Ganache Ethereum address>,
      text='some-text-tö-sign')
```

[image]